# Scala - restricting access to generic case classes

Tags: scala, generics, case-class, extractor

If I want a case class that cannot be manually constructed from outside a package, standard way would be something like this:

```
case class Foo private[p](a:A,b:B)
object Foo{
    def apply(c:C) = {
        require tit
        require tat
        Foo(c.a,c.b)
    }
}
```

Any way to do that if the class looks like this:

```
case class Bar[T <: MySomething[T]] private[p](t:T)
```

or will I have to content myself with writing a def that takes care of the case class creation and must be explicitly called?

**Edit**

Seems I wasn't clear about what my problem was ...

How can I pass the required parameters to the object / apply function?

Comment: Did you try it? Where did you get stuck? Did you get an error message from the compiler?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your problem. I've tried this `case class stuff[A] private[syntax](x: A)` and it works (provided you have the namespace).

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear, was I? The case class is fine, what I'm having trouble with is the object / apply function. How can I pass the parameters to the object?

Comment: You pass the parameters exactly the same way you pass them in your first example. What part are you having trouble with? If you're asking about the *type* parameters you just do `Bar[MyThingThatImplementsMySomething](c.a)`.